# Append a a hash to a CSV in Ruby 1.8

Tags: ruby, csv

How to append to a array of hashes into CSV in Ruby 1.8. There is FasterCSV for Ruby 1.9 but how do I do in 1.8?

This is what I have tried. `hasharray` is an array which contains elements which are hashes.

```
CSV.open("data.csv", "wb") { |csv|
  hasharray.each{ |oput|
    oput.to_a.each {|elem| csv << elem}
  }
}
```

This way puts all the data in the CSV but it puts them one below another instead of side-by-side.

Comment: It sounds like you want an arbitrary number of columns but only one row in your CSV -- is this true?

Comment: You can read the documentation for the Ruby 1.8 CSV library for yourself: http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.8.7/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html

Comment: CSV isn't such a great format for storing hashes.  Maybe take a look at [JSON](http://www.json.org/) or [YAML](http://www.yaml.org/)?

Comment: @sarnold I want all the keys in the row and values for each of the elements in hasharray in the columns

Comment: @XavierHolt I did it in JSON.I was trying in CSV.Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 1):

When iterating over hashes, you want to use two arguments in the block, one for the key, the other for the value.  Consider:

```
hasharray.each { |k,v| puts "#{k},#{v}" }
```